# Is there a division operation that produces both quotient and reminder?

Tags: scala, math, division, modulo

Currently I write some ugly code like

```
    def div(dividend: Int, divisor: Int) = {
        val q = dividend / divisor
        val mod = dividend % divisor
        (q, mod)
    }
```

Is it specified in standard library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No (except for `BigInt`, as mentioned in other answers), but you can add it:

```
implicit class QuotRem[T: Integral](x: T) {
  def /%(y: T) = (x / y, x % y)
}
```

will work for all integral types. You can improve performance by making separate classes for each type such as

```
implicit class QuotRemInt(x: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def /%(y: Int) = (x / y, x % y)
}
```

Comment: In terms of optimization both `divison` and `mod` are expensive operation, and we performing them both. Is there a way to take both results with one process?

Comment: One which works for all `Integral` `T` (`Int`, `Long`, `BigInt`, etc.)? No. Whether it can be done for `Int` or for `Long` specifically, should be asked in a separate question; but if it can, I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler does it automatically.

Comment: You can of course do `val z = x / y; (z, x - z * y)` to avoid `mod`, but it may well end up being slower.

Answer (score 28):

A bit late to the game, but since Scala 2.8 this works:

```
import scala.math.Integral.Implicits._

val (quotient, remainder) = 5 /% 2
```

Comment: Looking at the [source (Integral.scala)](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/d96b8eb48e83d400c03663a05b66ec218ead9c14/src/library/scala/math/Integral.scala#L24), this is just syntactic sugar for doing two separate operations in one go.

Comment: While it is substantially slower because it forces the use of a Tuple2 for the return value (unless there is a Tuple2[Int, Int] operation of which I am unfamiliar), it does mean that if the implementation is upgraded at some point to efficiently perform both operations at once (say an enhancement in the JVM itself), your code won't have to change to gain the efficiency. I plan to explicitly test the performance difference involving the Tuple2 overhead. I'll come back here and post a link to the results when I finish.

Comment: For those who prefer selectively bringing in implicits (there's a reason implicits have been redesigned in Scala 3), the actual import is `math.Integral.Implicits.infixIntegralOps`.

Answer (score 6):

In `BigInt`, note `/%` operation which delivers a pair with the division and the reminder (see [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.math.BigInt)). Note for instance

```
scala> BigInt(3) /% BigInt(2)
(scala.math.BigInt, scala.math.BigInt) = (1,1)

scala> BigInt(3) /% 2
(scala.math.BigInt, scala.math.BigInt) = (1,1)
```

where the second example involves an implicit conversion from `Int` to `BigInt`.

Comment: Ow.  Do **NOT** consider doing that with integers unless you can tolerate math being 60x slower than usual (separate invocation of % and /)!

Comment: There is a rather better implicit-based solution. This one gives a wrong result type, performs horribly, and allows calling other undesired methods on `Int` as well.

Answer (score 0):

BigInt does it

```
def /%(that: BigInt): (BigInt, BigInt)
```

> Division and Remainder - returns tuple containing the result of divideToIntegralValue and the remainder.